# How to fixe lines' s result of a query with JQL language

Tags: jpa, jql

I wanna to know How to fixe  lines' s result of a query with JQL language , like "LIMIT" in SQL ?

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to do something like this "select * from student LIMIT 30" in JQL. It is equivalent of "LIMIT" i want to know

Comment: and that method setMaxResults ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JPA, you do not specify this in the query string, but on a `Query` object you create from your query string, using `setMaxResults`:

```
TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createQuery("select s from Student s", Student.class);
query.setMaxResults(30);
List<Student> first30Students = query.getResultList();
```